# Add only 1 char into String

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible to change 1 char into String from code in Kotlin ?
I think yes, but I don't know how.

```
   <string name="carID">Id: </string>
```

Currently I change whole String like:

```
carID.text = car.id.toString()
```

but I want add only number to this ID:

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a char to a string:

```
val myChar = '1'
val myString = Character.toString(myChar )
```

Now, you can concat the new string to your other string:

```
val myIdString = "Id: $myString"
```

This is of course just the mechanics, you will need to adapt the code as you need and of course there are short-cuts if you want: this was purely for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Change your string resource like this:

```
<string name="carID">Id: %1$s</string>
```

and you use it:

```
carID.text = String.format(getString(R.string.carID), "1")
```

the text will be: `Id: 1`